# Ways of handling serious problems on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, error-handling, notifications

Say you are doing something critical to the app's usability at startup (like copying the SQLite DB or setting up CoreData) and something goes wrong that doesn't cause a crash but you don't want the user to continue. What can you do?

Currently my app has `abort()` and `NSAssert(false,...)` calls to make sure the app doesn't continue, obviously after the error has been logged. But somehow I think its not going to score points with Apple on the app store.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do in such situations? I understand for instance that if there is no connectivity you can put your app in 'offline' mode but lets say the DB couldn't be properly setup (for argument sake). There is no 'offline' for that and so the user cannot continue. The user needs to quit the app and try again or report the problem. Wouldn't you agree, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can show some alert view on click of any button if database is not updated like "Application failed to update data from server" and If data is updated then user can access some views otherwise view  transition will be prevented and alert will be shown.You can use also third party feedback tools that will pop up when application is about to crash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for late reply. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to create a view that has a message on it explaining to the user that a critical error has occurred and explained some steps to follow to resolve it. It prevents the user from using the app until it is resolved. So if the DB is missing or the model schema doesn't match the DB schema it will bring up that view.
Its one way of doing it that I took. If anyone has a different way, I'd like to hear it.